# Dialog box displayed by EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for:) apparently hidden behind overlay

Tags: ios, overlay, ios10, eventkit

My app's `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions:)` is creating an [overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355847/ios-present-modal-view-controller-on-startup-without-flash/28814500#28814500) like this:

```
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
let launchStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LaunchScreen", bundle: nil)
let overlayView = launchStoryboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!.view!
window.addSubview(overlayView)
```

The app's initial view controller as defined in `Main.storyboard` is a `UITabBarController` whose 1st tab contains a `UINavigationController`. `viewDidLoad()` of its root view controller calls `EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for:)`.

At this point the app seemingly stalls and only the overlay is visible. When I stop the app the dialog box that asks whether the app should be allowed to access the calendar appears. It was apparently hidden below the overlay.

How can I ensure that the dialog box appears at the very front of the screen so the user gets a chance to answer its actual question?

**UPDATE** Here is more information about the general context in response to questions: The reason for the code in the app's delegate is that -- unless it has  occurred on a previous launch -- I need to prompt the user for server credentials, obtain data from the server and store some of this data in `EKEvent`s. The overlay supports presenting the view controller for obtaining the user’s credentials (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355847/ios-present-modal-view-controller-on-startup-without-flash/28814500#28814500)). The overlay will be removed when data has been received from the server. The call to `makeKeyAndVisible` is necessary in order for `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` to receive a value despite the early stage in the app’s life cycle. That value is required for presenting the said view controller for obtaining credentials.

Comment: Are you sure you have this tab view controller in the LaunchScreen storyboard? It usually contains just the launch screen (as the name suggests) and the rest would be in a Main storyboard... Also did you try to set a breakpoint in your view controller to see if it even gets there?

Comment: @kender No, the tab view controller is not in LaunchScreen storyboard, but in Main.storyboard (see edit).

Comment: what's the reason for the code in your AppDelegate then? Do you remove the overlay at any point? And what if you don't makeKeyAndVisible the overlay window?

Comment: @kender I've updated the Q to answer the questions you have raised. (All of this has worked until reason, so the general approach is perhaps reasonable.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not that the dialog box was hidden behind the overlay but that I called `EKEventStore`'s `requestAccess(to:completion:)` synchronously (by waiting after the call for a semaphore that was signaled inside the completion handler) inside `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions:)`. Hence the entire app stalled and the dialog box was not even displayed.

The solution consisted in requesting access asynchronously. The following scheme is currently good enough:

- instance variable `calendarEvent` is `nil` if access to an `EKCalendar` was not (yet) granted
- `requestAccess(to:completion:)` is called from inside `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions:)`
- `calendarEvent` is set to this `EKCalendar` in completion handler of `requestAccess(to:completion:)`
- before reading or writing to calendar app checks if `calendarEvent != nil`
- during cycle of run loop with call to `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions:)` `calendarEvent` remains `nil`; app behaves as if calendar were empty
- during later cycles of run loop `calendarEvent` has been set; app actually writes to calendar only during those later cycles