# Presenting a specific view controller once immediately after launch screen closes

Tags: swift, viewdidappear

I have a 1-screen tutorial View Controller. I want this tutorial VC to show only once (userdefaults), but I want a smooth transition from when the launch screen finishes -> tutorial VC.

Right now - the launch screen finishes, then the main interface of the App shows for a split second, then the tutorial VC shows up. I want to remove this "flashing" of the main interface.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if !didShowTut {
        fireTutorial()
        didShowTut = true
    }
}

func fireTutorial() {
    let tutVC = UIStoryboard(name: "FirstTutorial", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TutorialSBID") as UIViewController
    tutVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    self.present(tutVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Any help to create a smooth transition from Launch screen -> Tutorial VC would be appreciated.

Comment: write this code in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidAppear

Comment: @Joe on first time, set the tutorial VC as window's root view controller. when tutorial finishes, change window's root view controller again with your app's main interface.

Comment: @ShebinKoshy - Currently working on your suggestion as a solution.

Comment: @Joe Cool. Thanks for informing.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355847/ios-present-modal-view-controller-on-startup-without-flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with a slightly different approach to solve this.

I embedded the main app VC in a navigation controller, then pushing the tutorialVC in App Delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
let tutorialVC = UIStoryboard(name: "FirstTutorial", bundle: nil)
let firstVC = tutorialVC.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TutorialSBID") as UIViewController
if let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
{
    navigationController.pushViewController(firstVC, animated: false)
}
return true
```

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting the tutVC on the viewDidAppear func which is executed after the screen has been loaded.

try calling the fireTutorial() on `override func viewDidLoad()` or on the `override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` methods that get executed before the screen is loaded.

Comment: I did try that; the VC never loads up if i put fireTutorial() in either viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Comment: @Joe which one is the app root view controller?

Comment: The main VC is the root. I suppose for the very first App load, the tutorial VC should be root, as suggested above by Shebin?

Comment: @Joe this is probably because you are not using a navigation controller and the main VC is set as the root in the storyboard.

You can add a navigation controller, set it as the entry point of your app and set the main VC as the root VC of the Navigation controller.

After that you will be able to call fireTutorial in the ViewWillAppear or set up a modal segue.

Comment: I've embedded my main VC in a navigation controller (in storyboard.) The TutorialVC now shows up when it's presented in viewWillAppear, but the 'flashing' is still occurring. (same result when presented in viewDidLoad).

Comment: @joe Are both view controllers in the same storyboard? If so, have you tried presenting with a seque?

Comment: No, the main App interface and tutorial each have their own storyboards.

Comment: I got this working. Check my answer. Thank you for your help! You jived some ideas to try, which ultimately worked.

Answer (score -1):

Write this code in viewWillAppear or viewWillLayoutSubviews() instead of viewDidAppear

Comment: The tutorial VC does not load if I put it in viewWillAppear. It just goes straight into the main App interface.

Comment: Then try writing the code in viewWillLayoutSubviews()